# java Calendar, sum month, year not changing

Tags: java, calendar, syntax-error

How can the year in the output add up according to the month's summation?

```
int sewa = 10
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    String cyear = Integer.toString(year);
    int mont = (now.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
    String cmont = Integer.toString(mont);
   int day  =  (now.get(Calendar.DATE) );
    String cday = Integer.toString(day);
    String date = cyear +"/"+cmont+"/"+cday;


 Calendar ex = Calendar.getInstance();
    int exyear = ex.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    String excyear = Integer.toString(exyear);
    ex.add(Calendar.MONTH,+sewa);
    int exmont = (ex.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
    String excmont = Integer.toString(exmont);
   int exday  =  (ex.get(Calendar.DATE) );
    String excday = Integer.toString(exday);
    String exdate = excyear +"/"+excmont+"/"+excday;
  System.out.println(date);
    System.out.println("+++++");
    System.out.println(exdate);
```

> now : 2018/3/25
>   +++++ after:2018/1/25
>   how ouput :2019/1/25

Comment: What gives you this output? the current code doesn't print it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You capture the year to a variable ...

```
int exyear = ex.get(Calendar.YEAR);
String excyear = Integer.toString(exyear);
```

... right before you add 10 months to the calendar ...

```
 ex.add(Calendar.MONTH,+sewa);
```

... which causes the `excyear` remains not updated.

To solve it, give the statements a correct order (Get Calendar -> add the months -> get Strings -> print). Or better using [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
Calendar ex = Calendar.getInstance();
ex.add(Calendar.MONTH, sewa);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
String exdate = sdf.format(ex.getTime());
System.out.println(exdate);
```

Prints out:

> 2019/01/25

Comment: nice,tanks your

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java 8 or newer version, please use [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) instead of [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class. It's very easy to add days, months and years using methods [`plusDays()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#plusDays(long)), [`plusMonths()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#plusMonths(long)) and [`plusYears()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#plusYears(long)). It's that simple:

```
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
    today.plusDays(20);
    today.plusMonths(1);
    today.plusYears(5);
```

[`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html)  and [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) were introduced with [JSR-310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) as much simpler, straightforward and easy to use replacement of [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) and [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html).

However, if you use older version of java, or need to use [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) and [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) for some other reason, you can increase the number of years the same way you did with the months, using

```
    ex.add(Calendar.YEAR, 5);
```

Comment: Good answer. If using Java 6 or 7, you may use `LocalDate` and the other `java.time` classes through [The ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/). You just need to `import org.threeten.bp.LocalDate;`, etc.